# How to run xorg on virtual console 7 and not 1

Tags: arch-linux, xorg

I'm using Arch Linux. The system starts the `xorg`-server right at boot. 
It is located on virtual console 1 so it hides the bootup messages, which disturbs me. How can I configure the system to start `xorg` on console No 7 like in good old times?

Comment: This is usually decided by your display manager like lightdm or gdm. The file you need to modify will depend on which one you use.

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you so much! I'm using SDDM and this gave me the clue to find the solution. (Which I will post below.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Pacmanwa's comment gave me the clue that this is a matter of display manager configuration.

As I'm using sddm, I had to create `/etc/sddm.conf.d/tty.conf` with contents

```
[X11]
MinimumVT=7
```